# Lubuntu 20.04 LTS too slow on Hp laptop

Tags: lubuntu, hp

I recently upgraded from Lubuntu 18.04 LTS to Lubuntu 20.04 on hp laptop. 
I used this:

```
sudo update, then 
sudo do-release-upgrade - d
```

Now it's so slow to load and run items.
Please help.
Regards

Comment: What did you upgrade from, and what exactly got slower?

Comment: From Ubuntu 18lts. It had worked well for me.

Comment: Did the boot time got slower or application loading time?

Comment: Please clarify.  Ubuntu 18? Do you mean Ubuntu Core 18? or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? or Lubuntu 18.04 LTS?   Lubuntu used LXDE so a re-install is the supported way to move from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS because of the change of desktop to LXQt. The upgrade was possible but it left numerous issues that need to be worked over, so did you install? or follow the fix steps?  Are you using the same apps?  (LXQt is Qt based so older GTK+ apps use different libraries so extra memory is required if you use LXDE apps; what resources (esp. ram size) do you have?)

Comment: Application loading time is slow. For example if I click on opera browser it takes about 20-45se seconds to get loaded

Comment: I've also reinstalled the browser coz that's where I noted the problem after upgrading. But no improvements

Comment: Please answer @guiverc 's question. You used the tag `Lubuntu` but your title contains `Ubuntu`. Which **specific distro** is it? Also [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1233810/edit) your question to include the specs of your laptop, the distro, the method of upgrading etc.

Comment: Upgrade was from lubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Did you read the release notes (https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/) where it notes "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"  Did you apply fixes (the Lubuntu team documented many fixes before reaching the conclusion the issues varied on what software was added and most users would find it difficult such that re-install was easier).

Comment: Guiverc. Thanks for the update. I must have missed it greatly. I'll revert back to 18.04.

Comment: Before I switched to previous versions I realized that Firefox was OK with the system running as normal. When using Chrome or opera then things go slow. Maybe I can hold and observe the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from Lubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 **is not** recommended as it might break your system. Instead, back up all of your important files, and create a bootable USB or DVD with the [Lubuntu 20.04 image on it](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) and install Lubuntu 20.04.